# Error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied for table:

Tags: google-bigquery

I have access to the following [project's](https://support.censys.io/google-bigquery/bigquery-introduction) dataset. The data get updated daily. The table ends with the date and we can query any snapshot by specifying the date.
When I query 20180828 table, I get this error:

```
 Error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied for table: steady-circuit-91417:ipv4.20180828
Job ID: censys-myid-2018:US.bquijob_2719325_1659047ad10
```

However, if I change the date to the previous date which is 20180827 or the next date 20180829 I get results. The problem is I need to query the snapshot of 20180828.
Is this a problem related to BigQuery or any thing I can do from my side? or is it a project issue?

Please note that the table name in the view does not appear as what the error message shows. The error shows `steady-circuit-91417:ipv4.20180828` but in my query I am querying `ipv4_public.20180828`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table `ipv4_public.20180828` must be an [authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) of table `steady-circuit-91417:ipv4.20180828`, the error indicates you have permission to view `ipv4_public.20180828` but the permission for that view to see the source dataset must be misconfigured. This can only be corrected by the `steady-circuit-91417` project admins.